# Can I install cuda 10.2 for using tensorflow 2.1 or it has to be cuda 10.1?

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu

Can I install cuda 10.2 for using tensorflow 2.1 or it has to be cuda 10.1?
I am using ubuntu 18.04 and I have a NVIDIA Quadro P5000.

Comment: [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu) seems unambiguous: "TensorFlow supports CUDA 10.1 (TensorFlow >= 2.1.0)"

Comment: In most situations, CUDA 10.2 cannot be used as an alternative for applications linked against CUDA 10.1.  If you install TF binaries (as opposed to building from source), then you generally need to supply the CUDA version that the binaries are linked against.  These comments apply approximately for any 2 different CUDA versions, for any application that is linked against CUDA.

Comment: I have tried using CUDA 10.1 for TF 2.1 and it did not work. Any particular reason why you want to use CUDA 10.2?

Comment: @thushv89  It was only a question for me but seems to be impossible to do that.

Comment: I could successfully install tensorflow 2.1 with CUDA 10.1.

Comment: @Masoud, I just saw a serious flaw in my comment. I meant to say, "I have tried using **CUDA 10.2** for TF 2.1 and it did not work". And yes, it did work with 10.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

No, as per Tensorflow documentation, TensorFlow supports `CUDA 10.1` (TensorFlow >= 2.1.0), please refer compatible version [details](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Pytorch need CUDA 10.2 but Tensorflow need cuda 10.1. Is it a joke?
No, you can use cuda version 10.2 with tensorflow 2.0.
It is quite simple.
**WHY:**
When run "import tensorflow", the tensorflow will search a library named 'libcudart.so.$.$' in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. For tensorflow 2.1.0-2.3.0 with cuda 10.1, it's 'libcudart.so.10.1'. With cuda 10.2, we don't have 'libcudart.so.10.1', so there will be a error. 
In fact there are not any difference between cuda 10.1 and cuda 10.2, so we can solve this problem through the soft links.

**HOW**

> cd /usr/local/cuda-10.2/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/
> ln -s libcudart.so.10.2.89 libcudart.so.10.1

> /usr/local/cuda-10.2/extras/CUPTI/lib64
> ln -s libcupti.so.10.2.75 libcupti.so.10.1

> cd /usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64
> ln -s libcudnn.so.8 libcudnn.so.7

> vim /etc/profile
> export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-10.2
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:${CUDA_HOME}/extras/CUPTI/lib64
> export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
> source /etc/profile

Click the button to see the picture.
[Done!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cZet.png)